# How to get token only from jwt encoded token

Tags: jwt, cakephp-3.0

I am creating token using JWT in cakePHP. It is working fine. Now I want to store this created token into the database. For storing this token I need to get token only from JWT encoded data. It is returning a lot of data. I just need token. Here is the data that I am getting after generating JWT.

```
'{"data":{"helpers":[],"request":{"trustProxy":false},"response":{},"paginate":[],"components":[],"View":null,"passedArgs":[],"modelClass":"ApiCode","viewClass":null,"viewVars":{"data":{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImlkIjo5LCJzdWIiOiJFNzQxMzciLCJpYXQiOjE1NDU5MTY4MTgsImV4cCI6MTU0NTkxNjg3OH0.Uuf-HsoSiSAALupTSAv304TRceGohi2sTs_PjF3dzMw"},"_serialize":["data"]},"RequestHandler":{"enabled":true,"ext":null,"ajaxLayout":null,"request":{"trustProxy":false},"response":{},"componen'...
```

From above data I just need this token `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImlkIjo5LCJzdWIiOiJFNzQxMzciLCJpYXQiOjE1NDU5MTY4MTgsImV4cCI6MTU0NTkxNjg3OH0.Uuf-HsoSiSAALupTSAv304TRceGohi2sTs_PjF3dzMw`.

I have used `foreach` but it is not working. Also I have tried this one

`$data = (json_encode(compact('data')));
 var_dump($data['token']);`

None of them are working. 
Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: How are you creating said token?? usually what you do is $token = JWT::encode([
                          'sub' => $value,
                          'exp' =>  time() + 31104000  //= 60s * 60m * 24h * 30d * 12m
                      ],
                      Security::salt())

Comment: Yes I am generating token like this. And in `data` variable I am keeping all the thing generating jwt. So from `data` variable I just need token.

Comment: actually your question is not about JWT, but more like "How can I extract a certain field from a complex JSON  object?".